# oracle occi connection pool reports ORA-00001: unique constraint (%s.%s) violated error

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle11g, occi

I tried below code

```
bool Database::initializePool()
    {
        connPool_ = env_->createConnectionPool(userName_, password_, connectString_, minConn_, maxConn_, incrConn_);
        if (!connPool_)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

And it reported the error of :
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'oracle::occi::SQLException'
  what():  ORA-00001: unique constraint (%s.%s) violated

I guess it maybe because my laptop lost power and shutdown abnormally. What can I do to make it right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I exp and deleted and imp the database again. so it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

We where able to solve identical issuer.

Looks like the occi driver initialises error codes to 1, so every single time the driver "panics" is will look like "ORA-00001: unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"

In your case the database where returning additional information about password expiration date and that was crashing the driver. Reseting the password fixed the problem.